# cross compiling protocol buffers for arm

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, cross-compiling

I am new to Google's protocol buffers and I am having trouble with cross-compiling it for arm. I am not able to find any concrete solutions to my problem using google.
The steps I am following:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make -s && make install
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --prefix=/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/ --with-protoc=/usr/local/bin/protoc
make
```

I get an error when I run make.

```
google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:55:2: error: #error "No suitable threading library available."
#error "No suitable threading library available."
 ^
Makefile:3956: recipe for target 'google/protobuf/stubs/common.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [google/protobuf/stubs/common.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/protobuf/protobuf/src'
Makefile:1544: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/protobuf/protobuf'
Makefile:1451: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why bother with cross compiling? Why not just set up your CI system to compile *on* the target?

Comment: Looks like Google's Protocol Buffers requires a threading library for the target platform.  Are you on an embedded system?  Which OS are you using?

Comment: I do not have access to the target embedded system yet. I am using ubuntu 16.04 as my build platform. Protocol buffers is just a dependency for my actual code.